# Find length and remove first letter

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new with SQL, and I need to know how to find out what is the length of the ID number, and remove first letter if ID bigger eq 16, so I only have 15 numbers in id

```
SELECT DATE,
ID,
ADDRESS,
CITY,
Country
from myDb where DATE=TO_DATE('2020-10-31','yyyy-mm-dd') and ID=
(CASE when LENGTH(ID)=16 then LENGTH(ID)-1)
```

Comment: This is not entirely clear. What if the ID is 17 digits - then do you only remove the first digit and keep 16 digits? Or do you need to remove the first two digits then? Examples are good, but examples alone do not constitute a complete problem requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DATE,
CASE WHEN LENGTH(ID)=16 THEN SUBSTR(ID, 2, 15) ELSE ID END AS ID
ADDRESS,
CITY,
Country
FROM myDb
WHERE DATE=TO_DATE('2020-10-31','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: The text of the question says "if ID bigger eq 16" so you may want to use `>=` rather than just `=`.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to do if the id is greater than 16 characters.  However, I think the simplest solution is simply:

```
select DATE, substr(ID, -15) as ID, ADDRESS, CITY, Country
from myDb
where DATE = DATE '2020-10-31';
```

The `substr()` argument accepts a negative position argument, starting at that position from the end of the string.  Voila!  Exactly what you want to do.

The one caveat is if the length can be less than 15.  In that case, it would return `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` solves that issue:

```
select DATE, coalesce(substr(ID, -15), id) as ID, ADDRESS, CITY, Country
from myDb
where DATE = DATE '2020-10-31';
```

Also note that Oracle accepts date literals, so `TO_DATE()` is not needed.

Comment: The text of the question says "remove first letter if ID bigger eq 16" finding the last 15 characters is not the same as finding the 2nd through 16th characters when the string is longer than 16 characters.

Comment: @MT0 . . . The question also says "so I only have 15 numbers in id".

Comment: The full requirements are "remove first letter if ID bigger eq 16, so I only have 15 numbers in id". But, if you only want to apply half the requirements then you'll get the right answer half the time.